# How to force an if loop to reset [PHP]

Tags: php, sql

I would like to know how to force an if loop to reset
This code is launch when a user click on a button on my index page.

```
  <?php
    include 'connexionBDD.php';
    session_start();
    $commentNewCount = $_POST['commentNewCount'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sentencesen WHERE type = 'Fun' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //while 1
            $id = $row['id']; 

                    if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['stockID'])){ //Check if an id has been seen
                        break; //I would like this thing start the loop again
                    } else {
                        echo $row['type'];
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $row['phrases'];
                        array_push($_SESSION['stockID'], $id);
                    }
        }
    } else {
        echo "There is a problem, could you refresh the page ?";
    }
?>
```

The probleme is when the in_"array() = true" nothing appear on the screen, so i just want to have the if loop to start again and search for a content who never appear already.
Thank you everyone !

Comment: You can use "continue" instead of "break".

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seems to work :/
thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case like this where you are trying to find out if particular condition occurs - just check for that particular conditon. In your case just check for:

```
    if(!in_array($id, $_SESSION['stockID'])){
                    echo $row['type'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $row['phrases'];
                    array_push($_SESSION['stockID'], $id);
                }
```

Comment: Ok i try to working on it.Thank you for your answer !